# If a function is $L^p$ small, is its expectation with respect to a $\sigma$-algebra $L^p$ small?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, lp-spaces

This came up in my homework, but isn't strictly my homework.  I've just gotten very curious, and I keep going in circles trying to prove it.

Consider a probability measure space $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ and a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}\subseteq\Sigma$.  Let $p\ge1$.  Suppose $f_n\ge 0$ and $\left\Vert f_n\right\Vert_p\to 0$.   Must $\left\Vert E(f_n|\mathcal{A})\right\Vert_p\to0$?  For that matter, must $E(f_n|\mathcal{A})\in L_p (\mu)$?

Comment: [Conditioning is a contractive projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Basic_properties).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Jensen's inequality, 
$$E[|E[f_n\mid\mathcal A]|^p]\leqslant E[E[|f_n|^p\mid \mathcal A]]=E[|f_n|^p].$$

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize there was a name for it.  Jensen's inequality is exactly my question.